# Is my VPS server secure? Steps needed to make it secure, if not?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, linode

I'm running on Ubuntu and I'm currently on [linode](http://www.linode.com/?r=730cff7e814dc5981629917c8a60272dab0a5a6d) [Disclosure: Referral Link]. I have followed this tutorial and have successfully set up Virtualmin on my linode and its a breeze creating websites and managing domains using the Virtualmin panel:

http://www.propellingsolutions.com/2011/01/how-to-install-virtualmin-on-linode/

However, I'm a little worried about the security of my server. I am not proficient with Linux stuff. SSH is enabled. What steps do I need to take to keep my server safe from hackers and exploiters? Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a decent article from linode on this topic:
http://library.linode.com/security/basics/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! I was stupid enough to ignore the Linode Library xD

Comment: Yeah the linode library has a lot of good stuff in it.  IMO though some of these security recommendations are a bit pointless when the Linode admin tool (which gives access to *everything*) does not implement them (pure username/password).